# How do I Login to asp.net application through a link send via email

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

**Short Story:** I'm a Newbie in application security. I need to implement a login via email.

**Long Story:** I have built a basic web chat application using SignalR, now i'm working in saving conversation in SQLServer Db. But my next challenge is to create a chat invitation email that will be send to all users from my db. The email should contain a link that when users will click they will be redirected to the chat web-page and automatically signed in.

**My question is:** Can it be done? And if it can, how can it be done

Thank you for your help!

Comment: bad design to auto login with a url link. Make an encode parameter, and send it with the link. Don't forget to add some expire inside the parameters that you send.

Comment: You can always start with Wikipedia which have reasonable explanation of what you trying to allow - [CSRF, also known as a one-click attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the email client will not give you ability to authenticate, but you can open from email link page A which redirects user to page B on the same application. dummy page A (if application hosted on local intranet and windows authentication is configured on the application) will post to page B user identity.